# Connect IBM MQ version 8 using WMQInitialContextFactory

Tags: ibm-mq

I tried to connect to IBM Websphere MQ 8 version using WMQInitialContextFactory.

But seems like I can't connect. Does the WMQInitialContextFactory support for version 8 removed?

Note : I can connect to version 7 products without issue.

P.S. Before connecting to the IBM MQ I disabled the channel security using the following commands,

```
runmqsc MyManager
ALTER QMGR CHLAUTH(DISABLED)
REFRESH SECURITY TYPE(CONNAUTH)
```

Seems like for Version 8 channel authentication disable approach doesn't work.

The error I'm getting is "Root exception is com.ibm.mq.MQException: MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2035'."

Comment: Please can you post details of the error and stack trace and any steps you've taken to debug the problem please.

Comment: @Calanais I've updated the post with error message I'm getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not bothered about security / authentication, you might also want to disable CONNAUTH as well as CHLAUTH:

```
ALTER QMGR CONNAUTH(' ')
```

Then refresh security again as you originally had in your question.

If that doesn't work, look in the queue manager error log for the reason why the MQ reason code 2035 (MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED) is being returned to the client.

Answer (score 0):

I think the likely reason could be connauth in v8 as explained in the previous answer. The following page will be helpful to debug 2035 errors.

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/96960515-2ea1-4391-8170-b0515d08e4da/entry/MQ_Problem_Determination_MQ_authorization_security_2035_errors?lang=en